# Vaadin ComboBox always displays the previous value if select() is called

Tags: java, gwt, combobox, vaadin

I have a custom ComboBox, where as user types the values are loaded from a webservice. If no values are found, I want to reset the combobox to empty value. However, this does not work if the comboBox has been initialized with some preselected value. If I call comboBox.select("") or even comboBox.setValue(null) the previous preselected value is shown, even though I call removeAllItems. This sound like a comboBox bug to me, but maybe somebody knows a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The `comboBox.setValue(null)` should work, just make sure to set the combobox immediate (`comboBox.setImmediate(true)`) and DO NOT specify the null selection id to something (like: `comboBox.setNullSelectionItemId("null")`).

Comment: That doesn't work. In case, there was already something in the field the set(null) just sets the value to null, but on the frontend the text stays there.

Comment: A `requestRepaint()` call doesn't help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I think there is a bug in the frontend part of the widget, tried to look into it, but don't have enough time and it wasn't that critical for me.

Comment: How exactly are you populating the combo? Can I see the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is the browser that fill input from its memory? Try to clean cache and form recorded value.